# Gift amount that can be received in one year from Foreigner

Tags: united-states, non-resident, gift-tax

I am a US Citizen . What amount can I receive as a gift in one year from my parents who are not US Citizens [or green card holders].

Do I have to declare these gifts and is it to be declared at the time of filing my taxes through form 3520?

Comment: welcome to money.SE. Please take the Tour and read more about what makes this Q&A site unique. Nice first question, hope you stick around.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/gifts-from-foreign-person):

> In general, a foreign gift is money or other property received by a
> U.S. person from a foreign person that the recipient treats as a gift
> or bequest and excludes from gross income.  A “foreign person” is a
> nonresident alien individual or foreign corporation, partnership or
> estate.

Further down it states that if it is over $100,000 in aggregate, then it must be reported on the Form 3520. But there is no "maximum" that you can receive.

According to [TurboTax](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2356211-cash-gift-from-parents-overseas):

> The US tax rules (in best of my knowledge) says that If a foreign
> citizen/residents want to send a gift (cash etc) to a US Citizen/legal
> resident and amounts will be less than $100000 then there is no US tax
> requirement but in case amount exceed $100000 then US Citizen/legal
> resident have to report in Form No. "3520" to IRS. But I advise always
> file form 3520 (whatever the amount) to support of your bank account
> trail for future reference. There will be no tax at all in the above
> situation.

So from the above two sources, you **must** file a Form 3520 if it's over $100,000. As always, please contact a CPA regarding complex tax returns/questions.

Comment: Thank you. As a us citizen can I give gifts to different people in one financial year of $14,000 each . Will those be tax free as I have not given to one person over 14,000?

Comment: @MEHER You can give individuals up to $14,000 without having either party pay taxes. But there is a lifetime limit of 5.45 million (in 2016). https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/Tax-Planning-and-Checklists/The-Gift-Tax/INF12036.html

Comment: @meher don't ask questions in comments, make a separate post. We can't up/down vote comments and they get lost. Also Michael, don't answer in comments either XD.